# For checking stationarity for applying Granger Causality Test, should the range of both the time series be same?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, granger-causality

I have 2 time series - one is for scores of people in a survey and the other for the sales of a product for 10 distinct countries. The survey data is categorized into 3 categories for each country. So, we have 10 * 3, i.e. 30 pairs. The data for the former is from April 2018 till Mar 2023 whereas for the latter, we have data from 2013. The aim is to identify the scores of which survey metric can be used to forecast the sales of the product for each country.

Stationarity of both time series is an underlying condition for Granger Test. I'm using the Augmented Dickey Fuller test for checking the stationarity of each country - metric pair and the sales data for each country. **My concern is that whether I should use the common time period for checking the stationarity of both the time series** which will be between 2018 till 2023 (that of survey data's)? In that case, I'll have to limit my data for sales as it is since 2013.

I have tried applying Dickey-Fuller on both the time series (by limiting and not limiting the sales data), both are giving drastically different results